# Merging columns in R (dplyr or any other package)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame called 'Health_Difficulties' that looks like the one below. I would need to merge:

```
Health_Difficulties = data.frame(
X = c(2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2),
Y = c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2),
Z = c(2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1)
)
```

into a new column named W, in order to eliminate the 3 columns and only keep W. What I'm trying to accomplish with this merger is that if either X or Y or Z has a 1, it would record a 1 on the W column, else if neither of the three columns has a 1, it would record a 2.

I'm new in R and have checked out dplyr but so far no luck. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: I'm removing the `[merge]` tag because that's usually associated with combining *datasets*, not *columns*.  I'm removing the `[coalesce]` tag because that's usually associated with combining columns with missing/null cells.  I'm not sure of a good tag to replace them, but I like @Jakub.Novotny's solution with `pmin()`.

Comment: @dan19_dan, check that your data frame is like what I have above? You should not use the <- assignment when creating a data.frame

Answer (score 2):

This should achieve what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

# creating you data
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  y = c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2),
  z = c(2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1)
)

# dplyr solution
df %>%
  mutate(w = pmin(x, y, z))

# base R solution
df$w <- do.call(pmin, df)
```

Comment: Maybe add a `baseR` option too? `do.call(pmin, Health_Difficulties)`

Comment: I have added the base R solution to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you . It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new vector or data.frame, if I get you correct.

So, you do

```
Health_Difficulties %>% 
mutate(W = 1+(rowSums(.==1)>0)) %>% 
select(W)
```

Comment: Thank you, StupidWolf! Very neat solution

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
library("tidyverse")

#Create Data
X <- c(2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Y <- c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2)
Z <- c(2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1)

#Create dataframe
xyz_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y,Z))

#Use ifelse to alter your data
xyz_table <- xyz_table %>%
  mutate(W = ifelse (X == 1 | Y==1 | Z == 1,1,
         ifelse(X != 1 & Y != 1 & Z != 1, 2, 0)))

#Create dataframe with only column W
health_difficulties <- xyz_table %>% select (W)
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you, John!